# Pegar o nome de uma lista de objetos dentro de um array e verificar se e igual ao nome passado por parametro da função que eu chamei

Tags: javascript

Preciso procurar no array na lista de objetos um nome específico, se esse nome for igual ao do parâmetro eu removo o objeto do array.
`nomeProduto` é parâmetro da função que eu chamei

```
pedido.find(function(produto)
{
   if(produto.nome==nomeProduto)
   {
      pedido.pop(nomeProduto);
   }                    
});
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

o método `find` do js, retorna o primeiro item que retornar `true` (satisfazer a pesquisa).

para o seu caso, recomendo usar o método `filter`, o qual retorna um novo `array`, também somente com os elementos que retornarem `true`, o que no nosso caso seriam todos diferentes do produto procurado, segue exemplo:

```js
var produtoProcurado = 'produto1';
var pedidos = [
    {
      idPedido: 1,
      produto: {
        nome: "produto1"
      }
    },
    {
      idPedido: 2,
      produto: {
        nome: "produto2"
      }
    },
    {
      idPedido: 3,
      produto: {
        nome: "produto3"
      }
    }
  ];
  
var compararProduto = (pedido) => pedido.produto.nome !== produtoProcurado;
var pedidosFiltrados = pedidos.filter(compararProduto);

console.log(pedidosFiltrados);
```